# Why return NotImplemented instead of raising NotImplementedError

Tags: python, exception

Python has a singleton called [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#NotImplemented).

Why would someone want to ever return `NotImplemented` instead of raising the [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError) exception? Won't it just make it harder to find bugs, such as code that executes invalid methods?

Answer (score 402, accepted):

It's because `__lt__()` and related comparison methods are quite commonly used indirectly in list sorts and such. Sometimes the algorithm will choose to try another way or pick a default winner. Raising an exception would break out of the sort unless caught, whereas `NotImplemented` doesn't get raised and can be used in further tests.

http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/32837.html

To summarise that link:

> "`NotImplemented` signals to the runtime that it should ask someone else to satisfy the operation. In the expression `a == b`, if `a.__eq__(b)` returns `NotImplemented`, then Python tries `b.__eq__(a)`. If `b` knows enough to return `True` or `False`, then the expression can succeed. If it doesn't, then the runtime will fall back to the built-in behavior (which is based on identity for `==` and `!=`)."

Comment: I would be careful using it, as this link points out near the end of the document.

Comment: When Python interpreter checks whether `a.__eq__(b)` returned NotImplemented, couldn't it just as easily catch NotImplementedError instead (and call `b.__eq__(a)` or whatever then)?

Comment: @Veky. Raising an exception probably has a higher overhead. Any overhead in a sort operation will get magnified by the size of the list so even if the difference was very small it would still make sense to find a faster implementation. You also don't want to be breaking out of your loops and reentering them which a try/catch implementation would require.

Comment: For the first point, even faster solution would be to automatically synthesize lt as reversed gt, instead of always calling something that will return NotImplemented - and Python doesn't do that. I don't think speed is the reason here. And for the second, I don't understand what you're saying: return will require just as much breaking out of loops as raise would. In fact, you can imagine return as raising a special Return exception, which is always caught in the calling scope.

Comment: >> "magnified by the size of the list"

At least, unless you have an O(n) sort the world ought to know about.

Comment: Agreed, speed is not the (only) reason. The biggest issue is that a and b could be different classes. Maybe class A a generic standard class written ten years ago by someone who'd never heard of class B, so `A.__lt__` has no idea how to handle the comparison. But maybe class B is an updated, specialized class that was specifically written to be backwards-compatible with class A, so `B.__gt__` knows _exactly_ how to handle the comparison.

Answer (score 288):

**Because they have different use cases.**

Quoting the docs (Python 3.6):

**[NotImplemented](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html#NotImplemented)**

> should be returned by the binary special methods (e.g. `__eq__()`,
>   `__lt__()`, `__add__()`, `__rsub__()`, etc.) to indicate that the operation is not implemented with respect to the other type

**[exception NotImplementedError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError)**

> [...] In user defined base
>   classes, abstract methods should raise this exception when they
>   require derived classes to override the method, or while the class is
>   being developed to indicate that the real implementation still needs
>   to be added.

See the links for details.

Answer (score 21):

One reason is performance.  In a situation like rich comparisons, where you could be doing lots of operations in a short time, setting up and handling lots of exceptions could take a lot longer than simply returning a `NotImplemented` value.

Answer (score 18):

Returning `NotImplemented` by a function is something like declaring that the function is unable to process the inputs but instead of raising exception, the control is transferred to another function known as **Reflection Function** with a hope that the Reflection Function might be able to process the inputs.

Firstly, the **Reflection Functions** associated with any functions are predefined. Secondly when the original function returns `NotImplemented`, interpreter runs the **Reflection Function** but on the **flipped order** of input arguments.

You can find detailed examples [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqzrLnZ9Y5M&t=91s)

Comment: Note that this answer is wrong: (1) this only applies to special functions like __eq__, __add__ etc..., your regular functions will return NotImplemented singleton as usual and (2) there is no such thing as "reflection function", this is something random bloggers made up. Official docs  ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented )  say "interpreter will try the reflected operation on the other type" - so if x.__add__(y) returns NotImplemented, python will call y._add__(x)

Answer (score 0):

If a special method supporting a binary operation is not implemented it should return `NotImplemented`. On the other hand, `NotImplementedError` should be raised from abstract methods inside user defined base classes to indicate that derived classes should override those methods.

Basically, `NotImplemented` helps the interpreter support a binary operation, whereas the `NotImplementedError` throws an exception. You can find a general usage [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations).

Comment: Slightly misses the point. You can also return `NotImplemented` to indicate that the operation isn't supported for _these particular arguments_, even if it is implemented for other arguments. For instance, imagine that the `int` class didn't know how to compare itself to the `float` class. Evaluating `5<10` would invoke `5.__lt__(10)` which would return `True`, but evaluating `5 < 10.1` would invoke `5.__lt__(10.1)` which would return `NotImplemented`. (In the second case, the interpreter would then call `10.1__gt__(5)`, to see if the float class knew how to handle the comparison instead)