# Compare object instances for equality by their attributes

Tags: python, equality

I have a class `MyClass`, which contains two member variables `foo` and `bar`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

I have two instances of this class, each of which has identical values for `foo` and `bar`:

```
x = MyClass('foo', 'bar')
y = MyClass('foo', 'bar')
```

However, when I compare them for equality, Python returns `False`:

```
>>> x == y
False
```

How can I make Python consider these two objects equal?

Answer (score 494, accepted):

You should implement the method [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        
    def __eq__(self, other): 
        if not isinstance(other, MyClass):
            # don't attempt to compare against unrelated types
            return NotImplemented

        return self.foo == other.foo and self.bar == other.bar
```

Now it outputs:

```
>>> x == y
True
```

Note that implementing `__eq__` will automatically make instances of your class unhashable, which means they can't be stored in sets and dicts. If you're not modelling an immutable type (i.e. if the attributes `foo` and `bar` may change the value within the lifetime of your object), then it's recommended to just leave your instances as unhashable.

If you are modelling an immutable type, you should also implement the data model hook [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

```
class MyClass:
    ...

    def __hash__(self):
        # necessary for instances to behave sanely in dicts and sets.
        return hash((self.foo, self.bar))
```

A general solution, like the idea of looping through `__dict__` and comparing values, is not advisable - it can never be truly general because the `__dict__` may have uncomparable or unhashable types contained within.

N.B.: be aware that before Python 3, you may need to use [`__cmp__`](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html#rich-comparisons) instead of `__eq__`.  Python 2 users may also want to implement [`__ne__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__), since a sensible default behaviour for inequality (i.e. inverting the equality result) will not be automatically created in Python 2.

Comment: I was curious about the use of `return NotImplemented` (instead of raising `NotImplementedError`). That topic's covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplemented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror

Comment: If you're using python3.7 or above, please use [dataclasses](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/).

Comment: Just a note about `NotImplemented`: "Changed in version 3.9: Evaluating NotImplemented in a boolean context is deprecated" (goes on to say that in a future version a DeprecationWarning will be emitted). So I suppose we should now just either return `False` or raise a `NotImplementedError` if strictly necessary (`False` strikes me as being preferable because any object **is indeed** not equal to another of another class: `NotImplementedError` suggests we're hoping this is a coding error spotting strategy, but probably not a good one).

Comment: It's not true that unhashable objects cannot be stored in dicts. They can. E.g. one can store lists in a dict. What one cannot do is label dict entries with lists (or other unhashable objects).

Comment: Any way of avoiding this code boilerplate , when eq operator is and AND of all member comparison ?

Answer (score 55):

You override the [rich comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) in your object.

```
class MyClass:
 def __lt__(self, other):
      # return comparison
 def __le__(self, other):
      # return comparison
 def __eq__(self, other):
      # return comparison
 def __ne__(self, other):
      # return comparison
 def __gt__(self, other):
      # return comparison
 def __ge__(self, other):
      # return comparison
```

Like this:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._id == other._id
```

Comment: Note that in Python 2.5 and onwards, the class must define `__eq__()`, but only one of `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()` is needed in addition to that. From that, Python can infer the other methods. See [`functools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) for more information.

Comment: @kba, I don't think that's true. This may work for the `functools` module, but **does not work** for standard comparators: `MyObj1 != Myobj2` will only work if the `__ne__()` method is implemented.

Comment: the specific tip about functools should be to use the `@functools.total_ordering` decorator on your class, then as above you can define just `__eq__` and one other and the rest will be derived

Answer (score 29):

If you're dealing with one or more classes that you *can't* change from the inside, there are generic and simple ways to do this that also don't depend on a diff-specific library:

### Easiest, unsafe-for-very-complex-objects method

```py
pickle.dumps(a) == pickle.dumps(b)
```

`pickle` is a very common serialization lib for Python objects, and will thus be able to serialize pretty much anything, really. In the above snippet, I'm comparing the `str` from serialized `a` with the one from `b`. Unlike the next method, this one has the advantage of also type checking custom classes.

The biggest hassle: due to specific ordering and [de/en]coding methods, [`pickle` may not yield the same result for equal objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501577/cpickle-different-results-pickling-the-same-object), especially when dealing with more complex ones (e.g. lists of nested custom-class instances) like you'll frequently find in some third-party libs. For those cases, I'd recommend a different approach:

### Thorough, safe-for-any-object method

You could write a recursive reflection that'll give you serializable objects, and then compare results

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

BASE_TYPES = [str, int, float, bool, type(None)]


def base_typed(obj):
    """Recursive reflection method to convert any object property into a comparable form.
    """
    T = type(obj)
    from_numpy = T.__module__ == 'numpy'

    if T in BASE_TYPES or callable(obj) or (from_numpy and not isinstance(T, Iterable)):
        return obj

    if isinstance(obj, Iterable):
        base_items = [base_typed(item) for item in obj]
        return base_items if from_numpy else T(base_items)

    d = obj if T is dict else obj.__dict__

    return {k: base_typed(v) for k, v in d.items()}


def deep_equals(*args):
    return all(base_typed(args[0]) == base_typed(other) for other in args[1:])
```

Now it doesn't matter what your objects are, deep equality is assured to work

```py
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
>>>
>>> a = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=42)
>>> b = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=42)
>>> 
>>> deep_equals(a, b)
True
```

The number of comparables doesn't matter as well

```py
>>> c = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=1000)
>>> deep_equals(a, b, c)
False
```

My use case for this was checking deep equality among a diverse set of *already trained* Machine Learning models inside BDD tests. The models belonged to a diverse set of third-party libs. Certainly implementing `__eq__` like other answers here suggest wasn't an option for me.

### Covering all the bases

You may be in a scenario where one or more of the custom classes being compared *do not have a `__dict__` implementation*. That's not common by any means, but it is the case of a subtype within sklearn's Random Forest classifier: `<type 'sklearn.tree._tree.Tree'>`. Treat these situations on a case by case basis - e.g. **specifically**, I decided to replace the content of the afflicted type with the content of a method that gives me representative information on the instance (in this case, the `__getstate__` method). For such, the second-to-last row in `base_typed` became

```py
d = obj if T is dict else obj.__dict__ if '__dict__' in dir(obj) else obj.__getstate__()
```

---

Edit: for the sake of organization, I replaced the hideous oneliner above with `return dict_from(obj)`. Here, `dict_from` is a really generic reflection made to accommodate more obscure libs (I'm looking at you, Doc2Vec)

```py
def isproperty(prop, obj):
    return not callable(getattr(obj, prop)) and not prop.startswith('_')


def dict_from(obj):
    """Converts dict-like objects into dicts
    """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        # Dict and subtypes are directly converted
        d = dict(obj)

    elif '__dict__' in dir(obj):
        # Use standard dict representation when available
        d = obj.__dict__

    elif str(type(obj)) == 'sklearn.tree._tree.Tree':
        # Replaces sklearn trees with their state metadata
        d = obj.__getstate__()

    else:
        # Extract non-callable, non-private attributes with reflection
        kv = [(p, getattr(obj, p)) for p in dir(obj) if isproperty(p, obj)]
        d = {k: v for k, v in kv}

    return {k: base_typed(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

---

Do mind **none** of the above methods yield `True` for objects with the same key-value pairs in a differing order, as in

```py
>>> a = {'foo':[], 'bar':{}}
>>> b = {'bar':{}, 'foo':[]}
>>> pickle.dumps(a) == pickle.dumps(b)
False
```

But if you want that you could use Python's built-in `sorted` method beforehand anyway.

Comment: If you pass a dict to base_typed(), the line: `base_items = [base_typed(item) for item in obj]` in `base_typed(obj)` will return just the keys of the dict & all the actual data contained in the dict will be lost.

Answer (score 14):

With [Dataclasses in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html) (and above), a comparison of object instances for equality is an inbuilt feature.

A [backport for Dataclasses](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) is available for Python 3.6.

```
(Py37) nsc@nsc-vbox:~$ python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class MyClass():
...     foo: str
...     bar: str
... 
>>> x = MyClass(foo="foo", bar="bar")
>>> y = MyClass(foo="foo", bar="bar")
>>> x == y
True
```

Comment: [Raymond Hettinger's 2018 PyCon presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw) is an excellent way to get started with Python Dataclasses.

Answer (score 10):

Implement the `__eq__` method in your class; something like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.path == other.path and self.title == other.title
```

Edit: if you want your objects to compare equal if and only if they have equal instance dictionaries:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `self is other` to see if they are the same object.

Comment: -1. Even if this is two dictionary instance, Python will compare them by keys / values automatically. This is not Java...

Comment: The first solution can raise an `AttributeError`. You have to insert the line `if hasattr(other, "path") and hasattr(other, "title"):` (like [this nice example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) in the Python documentation).

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your specific case, you could do:

```
>>> vars(x) == vars(y)
True
```

See [Python dictionary from an object's fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields)

Comment: Also interesting, while vars returns a dict, unittest's assertDictEqual doesn't seem to work, even though visual review shows that they are, in fact, equal. I got around this by turning the dicts into strings & comparing those: self.assertEqual(str(vars(tbl0)), str(vars(local_tbl0)))

Comment: Excellent solution for my case, where I can't change the class itself.

Answer (score 5):

As a summary :

1. It's advised to implement `__eq__` rather than `__cmp__`, except if you run python <= 2.0 (`__eq__` has been added in 2.1)
2. Don't forget to also implement `__ne__` (should be something like `return not self.__eq__(other)` or `return not self == other` except very special case)
3. Don`t forget that the operator must be implemented in each custom class you want to compare (see example below).
4. If you want to compare with object that can be None, you must implement it. The interpreter cannot guess it ... (see example below)

   ```
   class B(object):
     def __init__(self):
       self.name = "toto"
     def __eq__(self, other):
       if other is None:
         return False
       return self.name == other.name

   class A(object):
     def __init__(self):
       self.toto = "titi"
       self.b_inst = B()
     def __eq__(self, other):
       if other is None:
         return False
       return (self.toto, self.b_inst) == (other.toto, other.b_inst)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the method `__eq__`:

```
 class MyClass:
      def __init__(self, foo, bar, name):
           self.foo = foo
           self.bar = bar
           self.name = name

      def __eq__(self,other):
           if not isinstance(other,MyClass):
                return NotImplemented
           else:
                #string lists of all method names and properties of each of these objects
                prop_names1 = list(self.__dict__)
                prop_names2 = list(other.__dict__)

                n = len(prop_names1) #number of properties
                for i in range(n):
                     if getattr(self,prop_names1[i]) != getattr(other,prop_names2[i]):
                          return False

                return True
```

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58824440/edit) and add further explanation to your code, explaining why it is different from the ten other answers. This question is *ten years old*, and already has an accepted answer and several very high-quality ones. Without additional details, your answer is of much lower quality compared to the others, and will most likely be downvoted or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing instances of objects, the [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) function is called.

If the == operator is not working for you by default, you can always redefine the `__cmp__` function for the object.

Edit:

As has been pointed out, the `__cmp__` function is deprecated since 3.0.
Instead you should use the [“rich comparison”](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) methods.

Comment: The __cmp__ function is deprecated for 3.0+

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this and placed it in a `test/utils` module in my project. For cases when its not a class, just plan ol' dict, this will traverse both objects and ensure

1. every attribute is equal to its counterpart
2. No dangling attributes exist (attrs that only exist on one object)

Its big... its not *sexy*... but oh boi does it work!

```
def assertObjectsEqual(obj_a, obj_b):

    def _assert(a, b):
        if a == b:
            return
        raise AssertionError(f'{a} !== {b} inside assertObjectsEqual')

    def _check(a, b):
        if a is None or b is None:
            _assert(a, b)
        for k,v in a.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                assertObjectsEqual(v, b[k])
            else:
                _assert(v, b[k])

    # Asserting both directions is more work
    # but it ensures no dangling values on
    # on either object
    _check(obj_a, obj_b)
    _check(obj_b, obj_a)
```

You can clean it up a little by removing the `_assert` and just using plain ol' `assert` but then the message you get when it fails is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setattr` function. You might want to use this when you can't add something inside the class itself, say, when you are importing the class.

```py
setattr(MyClass, "__eq__", lambda x, y: x.foo == y.foo and x.bar == y.bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works (in my limited testing) by doing deep compare between two object hierarchies. In handles various cases including the cases when objects themselves or their attributes are dictionaries.

```
def deep_comp(o1:Any, o2:Any)->bool:
    # NOTE: dict don't have __dict__
    o1d = getattr(o1, '__dict__', None)
    o2d = getattr(o2, '__dict__', None)

    # if both are objects
    if o1d is not None and o2d is not None:
        # we will compare their dictionaries
        o1, o2 = o1.__dict__, o2.__dict__

    if o1 is not None and o2 is not None:
        # if both are dictionaries, we will compare each key
        if isinstance(o1, dict) and isinstance(o2, dict):
            for k in set().union(o1.keys() ,o2.keys()):
                if k in o1 and k in o2:
                    if not deep_comp(o1[k], o2[k]):
                        return False
                else:
                    return False # some key missing
            return True
    # mismatched object types or both are scalers, or one or both None
    return o1 == o2
```

This is a very tricky code so please add any cases that might not work for you in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.value == other.value

node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(1)

print(f'node1 id:{id(node1)}')
print(f'node2 id:{id(node2)}')
print(node1 == node2)
```

```
>>> node1 id:4396696848
>>> node2 id:4396698000
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Bite code's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1227325/2915423) is correct. But I had to do slight changes to handle `None` values and objects of other types. Until I had it this way, `None` objects were treated as equal.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass                                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
@dataclass                                                                      
class GpsPointRaw:                                                                        
    lat: float                                                                  
    lon: float                                                                  
                                                                                          
    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:                                            
        if not isinstance(other, GpsPointRaw):                                  
            return False                                                        
        if other is None:                                                       
            return False                                                        
        return self.lat == other.lat and self.lon == other.lon
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get an attribute-by-attribute comparison, and see if and where it fails, you can use the following list comprehension:

```
[i for i,j in 
 zip([getattr(obj_1, attr) for attr in dir(obj_1)],
     [getattr(obj_2, attr) for attr in dir(obj_2)]) 
 if not i==j]
```

The extra advantage here is that you can squeeze it one line and enter in the "Evaluate Expression" window when debugging in PyCharm.

Answer (score -3):

I tried the initial example (see 7 above) and it did not work in ipython. Note that cmp(obj1,obj2) returns a "1" when implemented using two identical object instances. Oddly enough when I modify one of the attribute values and recompare, using  cmp(obj1,obj2) the object continues to return a "1".  (sigh...)

Ok, so what you need to do is iterate two objects and compare each attribute using the == sign.

Comment: In Python 2.7 at least, objects are compared by identity by default. That means for CPython in practical words they compare by they memory address. That's why cmp(o1, o2) returns 0 only when "o1 is o2" and consistently 1 or -1 depending upon the values of id(o1) and id(o2)

Answer (score -6):

Instance of a class when compared with == comes to non-equal. The best way is to ass the **cmp** function to your class which will do the stuff.

If you want to do comparison by the content you can simply use cmp(obj1,obj2)

In your case cmp(doc1,doc2) It will return -1 if the content wise they are same.