# Strong attribute type checking when creating a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coming from a Java background and I am used to POJO to define a data model. Basically what I want to define is a data model using Python classes with strong attribute type checking and not being able to add more attribute then the one defined (basically something similar to django model). For example I am trying to do create a class:

```
class A:
    element1: int
    element2: str
```

but in this way I am not forcing that A object will not have attribute element3.

What is the pythonic way to achieve that, is there any framework you advice for python 3.6+?

Comment: Have you checked [attrs](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: The _pythonic_ way is not to do it. If you want to write code which is just like Java, then actually writing Java code is much simpler than making Python behave like Java ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `__slots__`, you can find more information using the magic method `__slots__` here: [Slots docs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/__slots__magic.html).

> Slots are a nice way to work around this space consumption problem. Instead of having a dynamic dict that allows adding attributes to objects dynamically, slots provide a static structure which prohibits additions after the creation of an instance.

Keep in mind that this comes at a cost.

> It will break serialization (e.g. pickle). It will also break multiple inheritance. A class can't inherit from more than one class that either defines slots or has an instance layout defined in C code (like list, tuple or int).

I hope this information is sufficient.

Comment: In this way I am not able to check the type of the attributes as well as type hint is not supported :(