# Elegant solution in Python for strict objects without duplicating fields in __slots__?

Tags: python, class, pycharm, typing, code-inspection

We have a bigger Python project and the run-time errors became more and more annoying, like mistypings, that would be avoidable using a compiled language.
I started to use the typing feaures of Python to catch many errors in code "inspection" time instead of runtime, like in C++ or ObjectPascal.
Using type annotation and PyCharm is much better, though I have discovered a serious problem:

```
class TNormalClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x : int = 1

c1 = TNormalClass()
c1.x = 2
c1.y = 5  # no error signalized here, but should have been!
```

After searching on the Internet i've found a solution with `__slots__`:

```
class TStrictClass():
    __slots__ = ['x']
    def __init__(self):
        self.x : int = 1

c1 = TStrictClass()
c1.x = 2
c1.y = 5  # PyCharm code inpection warning + runtime error: "object has no attribute 'y'"
```

That's what I wanted, but e.g. we have an object with 40 long named members. Duplicating every name in the `__slots__` is far from elegant in the year 2022.

I've tried the library "autoslot", the `c1.y = 5` resulted in runtime error, but this error was not detected inspection time with the PyCharm.

Is there some feature already in Python or maybe planned something in 3.10+ which would help me to create my "strict" objects

- without duplicating every member in the `__slots__`
- and also works with the PyCharm code inspection?

br,
nvitya

Comment: I don't think you should think of using `__slots__` as "duplicating every name". What would you expect the behavior to be if someone mistyped the `__init__` method and wrote `self.y: int = 1`? That error wouldn't be caught unless `__slots__` is your "source of truth" for which attributes are valid.

Comment: I note that if `TStrictClass` is a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) the error checking seems to be better, even without using `__slots__` (at least, pyright catches the error).

Comment: I'd also suggest using `dataclasses` or maybe the `attrs` package if you want to set `slots` before Python 3.10

Comment: @larsks: Thank you for your notes. Maintaining a class with two screens of member definitions would be a pain with ```__slots__``` so I would like to avoid it. The ```dataclass``` without slots does not give runtime error for ```c1.y = 5```. PyCharm unfortunately does not catches it, even with ```slots```. Unfortunately I did not succeed to install ```pyright```, it seems it requires some node.js environment.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: [Prevent creating new attributes outside __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603502/prevent-creating-new-attributes-outside-init)

As the second answer there says, `__slots__` is the pythonic way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think I understand the concept of ```__dict__``` and ```__slots__```. But it is still much more complicated than in C++/Java/ObjectPascal. And one half of the identifiers are even String literals. I've seen good progress in the Python in the years towards the usability. I think this has to be solved too, and best without special decorators.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you probably want to try using [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) that were introduced in Python 3.7.  If you want more features or need to support older versions of Python you could try using the [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/) package that `dataclasses` was based on.

I'd write your code as:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class TNormalClass:
    x: int = 1
```

Note that `slots` was only introduced in Python 3.10, hence my references to the `attrs` package.

These declarations are exposed to Python's typing support, so will be picked by tools like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) and by editors like PyCharm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just tried the ```@dataclass(slots=True)``` with Python 3.10 and PyCharm 2022.2.3. ```c1.y = 5``` is a runtime error, mypy catches it at inspection time, but the PyCharm unfortunately not. Unfortunately the mypy gives too much false positive output at our current project (e.g. ```Skipping analyzing "wx": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker```), and more complicated to use it. It seems, that I need to wait for some PyCharm upgrade then...

Comment: you can tell mypy to ignore specific packages: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-library-stubs-or-py-typed-marker.  it's nice having mypy run as part of a CI system on commits to check for significant regressions.  can take some work to keep types annotated, but for some projects it's certainly worth it

Comment: Just thought to try and I get a diagnostic error as expected, saying `"Foo" has no attribute "y"`.  I'm personally using Helix, which in turn uses LSP for diagnostics.  I assumed PyCharm would also be using LSP as it's become the conventional way to add language support to tooling

Comment: One thing bothers me a little with the `dataclass` the field definitions are outside of `__init__` and so without `self`. Every other usage of the fields/members require the `self` in the code. I feel here a bit inconsistency, but I can live with it. For now I'll migrate to `@dataclass(slots=True)`, it seems that this is the best option for now.

Comment: See [PEP-526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) for the rationale behind this. The syntax feels natural to me, but I've been using it for a while now...