# how to set class attribute only if it is created during init

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 100

class Boo(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Boo, self).__init__()
        self.B = None


x = Boo()
print(x.A, x.B)

# 100 None
```

As shown above, I've created an instance of `Boo` with attributes `A` and `B`. Now I'd like to assign value to attributes only if they are created during `__init__`. i.e. if I set `x.A=0` it will work, but when I want to set value to a new attribute `x.C=False` it should do nothing.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603502/prevent-creating-new-attributes-outside-init

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are asking, but you probably want to use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to control which attributes *can* be created, then ensure that they are initialized in `__init__`.

```
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('A',)

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 100


class Boo(Foo):
    __slots__ = ('B',)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.B = None


x = Boo()
```

You can continue to modify the values of `x.A` and `x.B` elsewhere in the code (even if not created in `__init__`), but any attempt to create a new attribute like `x.C` will result in an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score -2):

You may try to override `__setattr__()` function of `Boo` class, and then you can set a condition to using `hasattr()` built-in function to check if the instance is already present with the given name or not, if it is present set the value otherwise do nothing, here is the code that may help you;

```
class Boo(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Boo, self).__init__()
        self.B = None
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            pass # or anything yo want to do in case instance not found
```

Comment: This will fail to set the `A` and `B` attributes.