# Pickling results to save to disk results in different size objects when using different number of cores for multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, filesize

I looked around but haven't been able to find the answer to this question. I'm fairly certain my code is fine but I've noticed when I run it and save the pickled results (a dictionary) to disk, the size of it is different depending on the numbers of cores I used.

```
Using 4 cores results in a file 48,418 KB
Using 8 cores (hyperthreading) results in a file 59,880 KB
```

The results should(and seem) to be the same so I'm just curious what's causing the size difference.

I did a quick sum on the two pickled objects and they both report the same number of items in each dictionary:

```
4 cores has 683 keys and 6,015,648 values
8 cores has 683 keys and 6,015,648 values
```

I suppose I could check that the values are the exact same for each key, but I think that could take quite a while to run.

The only code that might be causing this would have to be where it splits the data into chunks to process and those are:

```
def split_list_multi(listOfLetterCombos,threads=8):
    """Split a list into N parts for use with multiprocessing module. Takes a list(or set)
    which should be the various letter combinations created using make_letter_combinations().
    Divides the list into N (where n is the number of threads) equal parts and returns a dict
    where the key is the thread number and the value is a slice of the list.
    With 4 threads and a list of 2000 items, the results dict would be {'1': [0:500],
    '2': [500:1000], '3': [1000:1500], '4': [1500,2000]} and the number of threads."""
    fullLength = len(listOfLetterCombos)
    single = math.floor(fullLength/threads)
    results = {}
    counter = 0
    while counter < threads:
        if counter == (threads-1):
            results[str(counter)] = listOfLetterCombos[single*counter::]
        else:
            results[str(counter)] = listOfLetterCombos[single*counter:single*(counter+1)]
        counter += 1
    return results,threads


def main(numOfLetters,numThreads):
    wordList = pickle.load( open( r'd:\download\allwords.pickle', 'rb'))
    combos = make_letter_combinations(numOfLetters)
    split = split_list_multi(combos,numThreads)
    doneQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    jobs = []
    startTime = time.time()
    for num in range(split[1]):
        listLetters = split[0][str(num)] 
        thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(listLetters,wordList,doneQueue))
        jobs.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    resultdict = {}
    for i in range(split[1]):
        resultdict.update(doneQueue.get())

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    pickle.dump( resultdict, open( 'd:\\download\\results{}letters.pickle'.format(numOfLetters), "wb" ) )
    endTime = time.time()
    totalTime = (endTime-startTime)/60
    print("Took {} minutes".format(totalTime))
    return resultdict
```

Comment: Try it on something smaller and see what the difference is -- you probably afford to take the time to check that the values are the exact same for each key with a smaller number.

Comment: I should have thought of that! Ah, well. I tried as you suggested using a wordlist of 305 words (rather than almost 400k) and still the same problem even after ensuring the results were the exact same. 4 cores is 41 KB and 8 cores results in a 52 KB pickle file. Plain weird.

Comment: Just tried it with 5 words. This time same size file of 2KB, but if you open them in notepad the 8 core version has roughly 284 more characters than the 4 core. Yet the data is still the exact same when you unpickle them.

Comment: Since you're using the default pickle protocol which is ASCII, you should be able to visually compare the contents (or use a Windows diff utility) of the two files when they're different, and actually see what the extra stuff being put in is comprised of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From:
cPickle - different results pickling the same object
[cPickle - different results pickling the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501577/cpickle-different-results-pickling-the-same-object)

"There is no guarantee that seemingly identical objects will produce identical pickle strings.

The pickle protocol is a virtual machine, and a pickle string is a program for that virtual machine. For a given object there exist multiple pickle strings (=programs) that will reconstruct that object exactly."

Talk about a dilly of a pickle!

Comment: Ah, much ado over a trifle...that ought be in the documentation.