# Pytorch tensor pickling inconsistent between runs

Tags: python, pytorch, pickle

I'm trying to unpickle a pytorch tensor, but pickling it back yields different results across runs:

```
>>> import pickle

>>> tensor1 = pickle.load(f) # I cannot reproduce the issue with some minimal manually-created tensor, only with this specific file
>>> tensor2 = pickle.load(f)
>>> pickled_tensor1 = pickle.dumps(tensor1) 
>>> pickled_tensor2 = pickle.dumps(tensor2)
>>> pickled_tensor1 == pickled_tensor2
False
```

Below are the values of `pickled_tensor1` and `pickled_tensor2` respectively:

```
b'\x80\x04\x95\x98\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0ctorch._utils\x94\x8c\x12_rebuild_tensor_v2\x94\x93\x94(\x8c\rtorch.storage\x94\x8c\x10_load_from_bytes\x94\x93\x94B\r\x01\x00\x00\x80\x02\x8a\nl\xfc\x9cF\xf9 j\xa8P\x19.\x80\x02M\xe9\x03.\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x10\x00\x00\x00protocol_versionq\x01M\xe9\x03X\r\x00\x00\x00little_endianq\x02\x88X\n\x00\x00\x00type_sizesq\x03}q\x04(X\x05\x00\x00\x00shortq\x05K\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00intq\x06K\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00longq\x07K\x04uu.\x80\x02(X\x07\x00\x00\x00storageq\x00ctorch\nFloatStorage\nq\x01X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382183041680q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00cpuq\x03K\x04Ntq\x04Q.\x80\x02]q\x00X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382183041680q\x01a.\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x94\x85\x94R\x94K\x00K\x02K\x02\x86\x94K\x02K\x01\x86\x94\x89\x8c\x0bcollections\x94\x8c\x0bOrderedDict\x94\x93\x94)R\x94t\x94R\x94.'
b'\x80\x04\x95\x98\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0ctorch._utils\x94\x8c\x12_rebuild_tensor_v2\x94\x93\x94(\x8c\rtorch.storage\x94\x8c\x10_load_from_bytes\x94\x93\x94B\r\x01\x00\x00\x80\x02\x8a\nl\xfc\x9cF\xf9 j\xa8P\x19.\x80\x02M\xe9\x03.\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x10\x00\x00\x00protocol_versionq\x01M\xe9\x03X\r\x00\x00\x00little_endianq\x02\x88X\n\x00\x00\x00type_sizesq\x03}q\x04(X\x05\x00\x00\x00shortq\x05K\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00intq\x06K\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00longq\x07K\x04uu.\x80\x02(X\x07\x00\x00\x00storageq\x00ctorch\nFloatStorage\nq\x01X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382172016592q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00cpuq\x03K\x04Ntq\x04Q.\x80\x02]q\x00X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382172016592q\x01a.\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x94\x85\x94R\x94K\x00K\x02K\x02\x86\x94K\x02K\x01\x86\x94\x89\x8c\x0bcollections\x94\x8c\x0bOrderedDict\x94\x93\x94)R\x94t\x94R\x94.'
```

My question is why is it happening and how can I prevent this?

I am using Python 3.8; pytorch 1.7.0

Cheers, Hlib.

Comment: Why use pickle for pytorch? You are better off with in-built methods to save tensors.

Comment: @Aditya doesn't pytorch use pickle under the hood by default? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html

Comment: Is the `operator==` checking if the values in both the variables are same or is it checking the memory addresses of the variables ?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. This doesn't seem to occur with numpy arrays. So my guess is that PyTorch is doing something weird in its `__reduce__` implementation for the Tensor class. I would suggest asking about it on the PyTorch repo on GitHub. As a practical matter, you can just do `(pickle.loads(pickled_tensor1) == pickle.loads(pickled_tensor1)).all()` to check equality.

Comment: the two tensors `tensor1` and `tensor2` are not the same object, they differ in their storage (memory pointers). it seems like `dumps` encodes this difference, resulting in their equality comparison being false

Comment: @adeelh Now I actually found a related open issue in the pytorch repo: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/39383, thanks for the advice! The problem is that I don't actually need to compare the variables but rather have a consistent dump between the runs to allow a reproducible pipeline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cPickle - different results pickling the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501577/cpickle-different-results-pickling-the-same-object)

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the tensors, you see that they are the same values, so the pickling process is working fine.

What is happening? Just try to change one of the numbers that differ and you'll get an error when asserting the key is in the deserialized_storage_keys. That tells you that these numbers are object keys and generated by pickle.

Can you avoid this? you can use `torch.save`, and saves to file or a BytesIO buffer that you can read if you wanted a byte-string

```py
import torch
import pickle
from io import BytesIO

pt1 = b'\x80\x04\x95\x98\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0ctorch._utils\x94\x8c\x12_rebuild_tensor_v2\x94\x93\x94(\x8c\rtorch.storage\x94\x8c\x10_load_from_bytes\x94\x93\x94B\r\x01\x00\x00\x80\x02\x8a\nl\xfc\x9cF\xf9 j\xa8P\x19.\x80\x02M\xe9\x03.\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x10\x00\x00\x00protocol_versionq\x01M\xe9\x03X\r\x00\x00\x00little_endianq\x02\x88X\n\x00\x00\x00type_sizesq\x03}q\x04(X\x05\x00\x00\x00shortq\x05K\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00intq\x06K\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00longq\x07K\x04uu.\x80\x02(X\x07\x00\x00\x00storageq\x00ctorch\nFloatStorage\nq\x01X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382183041680q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00cpuq\x03K\x04Ntq\x04Q.\x80\x02]q\x00X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382183041680q\x01a.\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x94\x85\x94R\x94K\x00K\x02K\x02\x86\x94K\x02K\x01\x86\x94\x89\x8c\x0bcollections\x94\x8c\x0bOrderedDict\x94\x93\x94)R\x94t\x94R\x94.'
pt2 = b'\x80\x04\x95\x98\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0ctorch._utils\x94\x8c\x12_rebuild_tensor_v2\x94\x93\x94(\x8c\rtorch.storage\x94\x8c\x10_load_from_bytes\x94\x93\x94B\r\x01\x00\x00\x80\x02\x8a\nl\xfc\x9cF\xf9 j\xa8P\x19.\x80\x02M\xe9\x03.\x80\x02}q\x00(X\x10\x00\x00\x00protocol_versionq\x01M\xe9\x03X\r\x00\x00\x00little_endianq\x02\x88X\n\x00\x00\x00type_sizesq\x03}q\x04(X\x05\x00\x00\x00shortq\x05K\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00intq\x06K\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00longq\x07K\x04uu.\x80\x02(X\x07\x00\x00\x00storageq\x00ctorch\nFloatStorage\nq\x01X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382172016592q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00cpuq\x03K\x04Ntq\x04Q.\x80\x02]q\x00X\x0f\x00\x00\x00140382172016592q\x01a.\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x94\x85\x94R\x94K\x00K\x02K\x02\x86\x94K\x02K\x01\x86\x94\x89\x8c\x0bcollections\x94\x8c\x0bOrderedDict\x94\x93\x94)R\x94t\x94R\x94.'

t1 = pickle.loads(pt1)
t2 = pickle.loads(pt2)

b1 = BytesIO()
b2 = BytesIO()

torch.save(t1, b1) 
torch.save(t2, b2) 

b1.seek(0)
pt1b = b1.read()
b2.seek(0)
pt2b = b2.read()

pt1b == pt2b
```

returns

```
True
```

Note that the size of the resulting strings is somewhat larger (419 vs 747)

`torch.save` also takes additional parameters, like the `pickle_module` to use, or the `pickle_protocol`

See: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html for more details