# Python does not consider equivalent objects to be equivalent

Tags: python, class, object, logic

I am pickling, compressing, and saving python objects. I want to be able to double-check that that the object I saved is the exact same object that is returned after decompression and depickling. I thought there was an error in my code, but when I boiled the problem down to a reproducible example I found that python does not consider two seemingly identical objects created at two different points in time to be equal. Here is a reproducible example:

```
class fubar(object):
    pass

print(fubar() == fubar())
#False
```

Why does python consider these two objects to be not equal and what is the most pythonic way to check that two objects are indeed identical?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default equality comparison in Python is to check for identity (i.e. two objects are the same object).

According to the [Python Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Non-identical instances of a class normally compare as non-equal
>   unless the class defines the __eq__() method or the __cmp__()
>   method.

To create your own definition of equivalence, you need to define an *__eq__* method.  Here is one way to do it:

```
class fubar(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        'Fubar objects are considered equal if they have the same contents'
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return vars(self) == vars(other)
```

The return value of *NotImplemented* signals that *fubar* doesn't know how to make the comparison and is giving the *other* object a chance to do the comparison.

The [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) has this to say about *NotImplemented*:

> This type has a single value. There is a single object with this
>   value. This object is accessed through the built-in name
>   NotImplemented. Numeric methods and rich comparison methods may return
>   this value if they do not implement the operation for the operands
>   provided. (The interpreter will then try the reflected operation, or
>   some other fallback, depending on the operator.) Its truth value is
>   true.

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same objects. Check the values of `id(fubar())` and `id(fubar())` for example. You need to implement [your own equality method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) if you wish to redefine how equality works:

```
class fubar(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True # make this more complex
```

This method should return `True` when `self` and `other` are equal and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method to your class if you want define your own way of comparing two objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1227325/447599) answer. Basically, define your `__eq__` method to compare the `self.__dict__` of the to objects, which returns a dictionary with the attributes of the object.