# Assertion fails with same object

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

The unit test fails with the following exception:

```
def test_question_form(self):
    question = Question(question_text='Dummy question', pub_date=timezone.now(
    ) + datetime.timedelta(days=1), allow_multiple_choices=True)
    question_form = QuestionForm(
        {'question_text': question.question_text, 'pub_date': question.pub_date, 'allow_multiple_choices': 'on' if question.allow_multiple_choices else 'off'})
    self.assertTrue(question_form.is_valid())
    self.assertEqual(question_form.save(commit=False), question)
```

> `AssertionError: <Question: Dummy question> != <Question: Dummy question>`

After some manual assertion the object seem to be equal, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you probably created 2 instances of "Dummy Questions" objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your instances are not saved, the model instance returned by `form.save` with `commit=False` and the original unsaved object will never be equal (except you override the `__eq__` method of your model to handle this):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#eq):

> The equality method is defined such that instances with the same
>   primary key value and the same concrete class are considered equal,
>   except that **instances with a primary key value of `None` aren’t equal to anything except themselves**

Comment: What would be a solution to this except of overriding the equal method? Do I have to manually assert all model members?

Comment: See [compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes-in-python)