# Python operator for functionally equal objects?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, boolean

Just curious if there is a way in Python to compare two objects that are functionally equal, but expressed differently. For example, these two regular expression objects *mean* the same thing (both would match "5.5" or "5.55" or "5.5555"), but "a" is verbose.

```
a = regex.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
                   \.    # the decimal point
                   \d *  # some fractional digits""", regex.X)

b = regex.compile(r"\d+\.\d*")
```

Printing a == b evaluates to False.

Comment: It is not possible to compare 2 objects which are expressed differently. However, you can compare 2 objects by attributes. (refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes-in-python)

Comment: Are you asking about regular expression objects specifically or is it a general question. You always have the option of subclassing an object and defining or overwriting its [comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to have the behaviour you need/want.

Comment: This is actually quite tricky. And in general it's _impossible_ to create an algorithm that can determine whether two programs will return the same result on all inputs. Here's some info on this fascinating topic on [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/how-do-you-check-if-two-algorithms-return-the-same-result-for-any-input).

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, but restricting to *regular expressions* it is possible to determine equality. See also [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12267).

Comment: @ephemient Indeed, but I can't resist an opportunity to mention a connection to Turing's Halting Problem. :)

Comment: @wwii it's more of a general question, but I just happened to be working with regex's when it came up.

Comment: @CourtneyPruitt: Since your two regular expressions differ only in their representations, you could use something hacky to compare them: `repr(re.sre_parse.parse(a.pattern, a.flags)) == repr(re.sre_parse.parse(b.pattern, b.flags))`. Note that this cannot compare `\d\d` and `\d{2}`, since they don't parse to the same object.