# Object comparision in a list python, with index value

Tags: python, list, object

Lets say I have a class

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, item1, item2):
        self.item1 = item1
        self.item2 = item2
```

And a objects list of that class

```
object1 = Foo (1,2)  
object2 = Foo (1,2)
object3 = Foo (1,3)
objectlist = [object1, object3]
```

I would like to know whether object2 with same items is in the list of objectlist and after that I would like to get the index of it. In this case 0 index.

I can do this by

```
def __eq__ (self, other):
    return (self.item1 == other.item1) and (self.item2 == other.item2)
```

And a for loop. Since I could be able to check every index one by one, and got the index if it equals to that object. But can I do it with more elagant way?

Comment: You mean `object2 in objectlist`?

Comment: you could do  `return self.item1 == other.item1  and self.item2 == other.item2` and get rid of the `if` that not really serves any purpose

Comment: I edited my question thank you

Comment: Note that if you implement your `__eq__`, you probably want to also implement your `__hash__`. See the [documentation for `__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about?:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, item1, item2):
        self.item1 = item1
        self.item2 = item2


    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return (self.item1 == other.item1) and (self.item2 == other.item2)

object1 = Foo (1,2)  
object2 = Foo (1,2)
object3 = Foo (1,3)
objectlist = [object1, object3]

try:
    index_value = objectlist.index(object2)
    print(index_value)
except ValueError:
    index_value = -1
    print(index_value)
```

Comment: You mean this my friend? Maybe I am missing something but I got -1 as result.

Comment: @MericOzcan `__eq__` needs indentation, like this it's not part of the class.

Comment: I changed it, thank you @mkiever. It should work now

Comment: Thank you so this is the way ? O.o

Comment: @MericOzcan this is a way to do what you said, yes.

Comment: Ok thanks, ValueError is the right exception I believe. Lets wait if someone can come up with one line solution :D

Comment: @JonnyCrunch my friend can you also vote up my question

Answer (score 0):

The question is if you are going to differentiate between different *objects* but containing `item1` and `item2` of the same value.

If yes, then you do not have to check the contents of the object. Rather rely on the different identifier (`id(obj)`) of each instance of your class:

```
object2 in objectlist
```

If not, then your approach is (almost) the correct one and I am not aware of any better. In your case you are not strictly checking the class of both objects is the same rather - that they are *structurally* the same (i.e. they have the same members `item1` and `item2`).

You may also want to review the answers of the following question: [Compare object instances for equality by their attributes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes-in-python)