# equal class objects with Python

Tags: python

```
import unittest
from EarnClass import Employee
class TestGive(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.data = Employee('x', 'y', 'z')

    def test_give_default(self):
        #"""xxxx"""

        self.assertEqual(self.dane, 'x y z')
```

Output:

```
AssertionError:<EarnClass.Employee object at 0x027EA290> != 'x y z'
```

Comment: The output from your test is self explanatory. What is your question?

Comment: how can i equal class arguements with this object?

Comment: You need to explain to us why the string `'x y z'` should be anything like the instance of `Employee`. Perhaps you could update the question to include relevant parts of the `Employee` class.

Comment: `         def __init__(self, name, lastname, EarnYear):
                 self.name = name
                 self.lastname = lastname
                self.EarnYear = EarnYear

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes

Answer (score 0):

`'x y z'` is of type `str` and cannot be equal to an `Employee` instance (which is probably not of type `str` unless you inherited from it).