# Deleting a user-defined object(a card), from a list(hand of a player) in python

Tags: python, oop

Sorry I'm new to python, sorry, if the question is too basic. I am trying to write a code for a card game called pishti or bastra. Shortly, two players (in my case a user and a computer) have hands consisting of 4 cards each and there are some cards in the middle one of which is on top and visible to the players (others are closed). Shortly I was able to deal cards for the user with a list of four card objects. However, after the user plays one of his/her cards, I can't remove the card from the list as it cannot be found. (I tried to use .remove() and del) However, I can access the cards with list[index]
Here's my code (shortened to the parts related to this question):

```
import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.suit} {self.value}"
    def execute(self):
        return None
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ["Hearts","Spades","Clubs","Diamonds"]
        values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
        self.cards = [Card(value,suit) for value in values for suit in suits]
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Deck of {self.count()}"
    def count(self):
        return len(self.cards)
    def shuffle(self):
        if self.count() < 52:
            raise ValueError ("Sorry only complete decks can be shuffled.")
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self
    def _deal(self,num_of_cards_to_be_dealt):
        if self.count() == 0:
            raise ValueError ("Sorry, all of the cards have been dealt.")
        actual = min(self.count(),num_of_cards_to_be_dealt)
        dealt_cards = self.cards[-actual:]
        self.cards = self.cards[:-actual]
        return dealt_cards
    def deal_hand(self,hand_size = 4):
        return self._deal(hand_size)

deste = Deck()
kar_deste = deste.shuffle()


orta = (kar_deste.deal_hand())

print(f"The card in the middle: {orta[-1]}")
user_score = 0
comp_score = 0
while kar_deste.count() != 0:
    computer_hand = kar_deste.deal_hand()
    user = kar_deste.deal_hand()
    print(f"Your cards: {user}")
    while len(user) != 0:
        card_suit = input("Choose a suit: ")
        card_val = input("Choose a value: ")
        print(str(Card(card_val,card_suit)))
        user_turn = Card(card_val,card_suit)
        card_index = user.index(user_turn)
        del user[card_index]
        print(user)
```

When I run this code I encounter a value error(in the line with user.index()), stating the card is not in the list. However I can access to it by manually using it's index. Thus I don't know why this doesn't work. Do you have any idea, what might be the reason behind this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1227325/5987698) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.index` calls the objects' `__eq__` method, so you will have to implement it in `Card`. Otherwise the objects will be compared based on their memory addresses.

Possible implementation:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return all((isinstance(other, self.__class__),
                self.suit == other.suit,
                self.value == other.value))
```

Then

```
The card in the middle: Clubs 4
Your cards: [Diamonds 10, Hearts K, Clubs 10, Hearts 5]
Choose a suit: Hearts
Choose a value: 5
Hearts 5
[Diamonds 10, Hearts K, Clubs 10]
Choose a suit: Diamonds
Choose a value: 10
Diamonds 10
[Hearts K, Clubs 10]
Choose a suit: Hearts
Choose a value: K
Hearts K
[Clubs 10]
Choose a suit: Clubs
Choose a value: 10
Clubs 10
[]
...
```