# How to sort list of lists containing user defined objects

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list of lists of `"category"` objects in a variable called `"category_tree"`, which is a list:

```
[[<Category: State>, <Category: County>, <Category: Chicago>], 
[<Category: Animal>],
[<Category: State>, <Category: County>], 
[<Category: State>, <Category: County>, <Category: NYC>], 
[<Category: Animal>, <Category: Fish>], 
[<Category: State>, <Category: County>, <Category: LA>], 
[<Category: Animal>, <Category: Frog>, <Category: TreeFrog>, <Category: Fred>]]
```

I need to sort the top-level `list` by the `.name` properties of the underlying `lists`. I do not want to sort the underlying lists, just the top-level `list`.

Assuming the `.name` elements match what is listed here, this is what I'm trying to get:

```
[[<Category: Animal>], 
[<Category: Animal>, <Category: Fish>], 
[<Category: Animal>, <Category: Frog>, <Category: TreeFrog>, <Category: Fred>]
[<Category: State>, <Category: County>], 
[<Category: State>, <Category: County>, <Category: Chicago>],
[<Category: State>, <Category: County>, <Category: LA>], 
[<Category: State>, <Category: County>, <Category: NYC>]]
```

I can sort them by the first or the last column with:

```
category_tree.sort(key=lambda x: x[0].name)
category_tree.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1].name)
```

But the problem I'm running into is that they have variable numbers of columns, so I can't sort them this way for all internal columns.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this category tree? Seems more logical to use a dictionary for these type of things.

Comment: As far as what I'm trying to achieve -- I'm dealing with outputs from a django website back-end that I get in this form, and I can't change that part of it. I could convert them to some other form and then back to this, if needed. In the end, I just need to sort them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slighty modified example, with a possible solution:

```
class Category:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

items = [
    [Category('State'), Category('County'), Category('Chicago')],
    [Category('Animal')],
    [Category('State'), Category('County')],
    [Category('Animal'), Category('Frog')],
    [Category('Animal'), Category('Fish'), Category('Dog')],
]

items.sort(key=lambda x: [item.name for item in x])
print(items)
```

results in

```
[[Animal], [Animal, Fish, Dog], [Animal, Frog], [State, County], [State, County, Chicago]]
```

This relies on the ability of Python to compare lists directly, provided the individual items in the list can be compared properly. For integers, floats and strings, that is not a problem. For a (basic) class, it is, since it not defined by default.

If you have access to the `Category` class (i.e., you wrote it yourself), you can override `__eq__` and other magic comparison methods, which makes things a lot simpler (see e.g. [Compare object instances for equality by their attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes) ).

With help from the `functools` module:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering 
class Category:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.name < other.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

And then simply:

```
items.sort()
```

(`items` as before).

With the same result: `[[Animal], [Animal, Fish, Dog], [Animal, Frog], [State, County], [State, County, Chicago]]`.