# Python checking already exists element in list

Tags: python

I would like to make sure that the same film is added,
but unfortunately,
something is not working out. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, name, pegi, year):
        self.name = name
        self.pegi = pegi
        self.year = year

class Movies(Movie):

    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = []

    def addMovieToCollection(self, name, pegi, year):
        super().__init__(name, pegi, year)
        structure_of_movie = name + " - " + pegi + " - " + str(year)
        if structure_of_movie in self.collection :
            print("That movie like" + self.name + " already exists")
        else:
            self.collection.append(structure_of_movie)

    def showMovie(self):
        return print(*self.collection, sep='\n')

f = Movies()

f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 1", "blue sign", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 1", "blue sign", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 2", "+7", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 3", "+16", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 4", "+12", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 5", "+18", 1995)
f.showMovie()
```

Please Help me

Comment: "something is not working" what is not working? How someone can understand what do you mean by "something" you should tell exactly what is not working

Comment: the security of adding the same film does not work - foreach loop

Comment: You don't want to let the same film be added twice correct ? and the uniqueness check is only on the film name? not in the film name + year ?

Comment: this will help [Compare object instances for equality by their attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes)

Comment: @VikashSingh I would like to get it, but for now it does not work with the name itself

Comment: I mean, `self.collection.__eq__(CurrentFilm)` is going to compare the _whole_ `collection` to each of the films in it. It's like comparing a basket of apples to one single apple - they will _never_ be equal

Comment: As an aside, `super().__init__(name, pegi, year)` makes no sense in `addMovieToCollection`. And having `Movies` inherit from `Movie` also makes no sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so how do you inherit the constructor from the `Movie` class?

Comment: @powezka43 *in the constructor usually*. Why would you call the constructor every time you use `addMovieToCollection`? But again, *fundamentally* having `Movies` inherit from `Movie` is a broken design. A thing is not a collection of things. A collection of things *has things*. A collection of things is a separate type. Just *don't inherit* from `Movie` at all. Use *composition*, not inheritance.

Comment: @powezka43 Didn't you just update the question with working code from one of the answers? Why would you do that? Now the question "what am I doing wrong" makes 0 sense because the code works as expected and there is nothing _wrong_ with it. Could you please revert to the original code, clarify your question (provide expected and actual output) and mark the answer as accepted if it fixed your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `__eq__` and `__hash__` method in class, something like this:

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, name, pegi, year):
        self.name = name
        self.pegi = pegi
        self.year = year

    def __eq__(self, other): 
        if not isinstance(other, Movie):
            # don't attempt to compare against unrelated types
            return NotImplemented

        return self.name == other.name # and self.year == other.year
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
        # if you want to compare with year too.
        # return hash(self.name + str(self.year))   
      
    def __str__(self):
        # This is how each movie will be printed. 
        # You can improve the formatting here.
        return "Movie name: {}, Year: {}".format(self.name, self.year)

class Movies(): # it makes no sense that Movies should inherit Movie, don't do that.

    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = set()

    def addMovieToCollection(self, name, pegi, year):
        current_movie = Movie(name, pegi, year)
        if current_movie in self.collection:
            print("That movie like" + current_movie.name + " already exists")
        else:
            self.collection.add(current_movie)
            print("Added " + current_movie.name + " " + str(current_movie.year))
            
    def __str__(self):
        # Join the collection together how you would like to represent it.
        response = "\nMovies Collection:\n"
        for movie in self.collection:
            response += str(movie) + "\n"
        return response

f = Movies()

f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 1", "blue sign", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 2", "+7", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 1", "blue sign", 1996)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 1", "blue sign", 1995)
print(f)
```

output:

```
Added Iron Man 1 1995
Added Iron Man 2 1995
That movie likeIron Man 1 already exists
That movie likeIron Man 1 already exists

Movies Collection:
Movie name: Iron Man 2, Year: 1995
Movie name: Iron Man 1, Year: 1995
Iron Man 11995
```

Finally to print the movies I would advise you implement `__str__` method in both classes.
`Movie` class `__str__` should return 1 movie.
and `Movies` class `__str__` should return the list of movie.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that's help me but __str__ cant return me list of movies

Comment: it can if you join all movies names in `__str__`.

Comment: I tried but i have `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type set)`

Comment: You need to loop on the values and convert them individually to str and return that string after joining, updated the code with this.

Comment: @powezka43 that worked for you?

Comment: yeah, full solution thanks! im so bad :(

Comment: No not at all, you are only getting started, things will get better with time. Trust me and hang in there :) Keep practicing. 
PS: Also if possible accept the answer by clicking on the Tick mark if it helped you and upvoting :D

Comment: I had a 4 month break in programming (I was also learning JS and not Python) and maybe it makes me confused.

Comment: possible JS and python could be difficult to process together. But I would suggest you keep at it. You will get it in the end, keep solving problems :) All the very best.

Comment: Thank you, I think JS is 'biting' me with Python. Greetings :)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this will resolve your issue. Let me know if you meant something else.

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, name, pegi, year):
        self.name = name
        self.pegi = pegi
        self.year = year

class Movies(Movie):

    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = []

    def addMovieToCollection(self, name, pegi, year):
        super().__init__(name, pegi, year)
        structure_of_movie = name + " - " + pegi + " - " + str(year)
        #I removed the for loop here
        if structure_of_movie in self.collection : #IChanged this if condition as well
            print("That movie like" + self.name + " already exists")
        else:
            self.collection.append(structure_of_movie)

    def showMovie(self):
        return print(*self.collection, sep='\n')

f = Movies()

f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 1", "blue sign", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 1", "blue sign", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 2", "+7", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 3", "+16", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 4", "+12", 1995)
f.addMovieToCollection("Iron Man 5", "+18", 1995)
f.showMovie()
```

Comment: Not a downvoter. But when you posting answer you should explain how your answer solves the OP problem

Comment: Thanks for the info but i did mention the changes in the code and the rest was same code that i used which was there in the question. sow what else was needed to explain...just help me with this one more piece of info