# Python Get Difference Between Two Typed Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Actually i have a class called "Employee" containing the following properties:

```
class Employee:
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int
```

And further i've received two lists (from different databases) witch each item is a "Employee" instance. Something like

```
listA = [{id: 1, name: 'john  doe', age: 20}, {id: 2, name: 'marry', age: 27}]
listB = [{id: 1, name: 'john', age: 20}, {id: 2, name: 'marry', age: 27}]
```

How can i compare that two lists and return just what is different from another one?

ex: return a new list containing just the **john doe** instance.

Comment: why are you storing objects in the form dictionary? if you use dictionary then why creating class?

Comment: this will help [Compare object instances for equality by their attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes)

Comment: Why would  __john__ not be on the list?

Comment: @DYZ cause john has been changed on the newest data source (listA)

Comment: the goal is to return only the differential between the lists

Answer (score 0):

Go through all items of one list and select those that are **not** on the other list, and the other way around:

```
[item for item in listA if item not in listB] +\
[item for item in listB if item not in listA]
#[{'id': 1, 'name': 'john  doe', 'age': 20}, 
# {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 20}]
```

If the lists are large, you can improve performance by converting them into frozensets of items and taking the symmetric set difference:

```
setA = set(frozenset(l.items()) for l in listA) 
setB = set(frozenset(l.items()) for l in listB)
setA ^ setB
#{frozenset({('id', 1), ('name', 'john'), ('age', 20)}), 
# frozenset({('age', 20), ('id', 1), ('name', 'john  doe')})}
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of them suit my case. My goal is to return only differential between

Comment: That's exactly what my code does: calculates the difference between the two lists