# How to determine the correct user to update or delete the post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to update and delete post and it is happening but now I want users to Update and delete a post only created by them. Strating from delete this is my delete function

```
def delete_post(request , id):
        post=Post.objects.get(pk=id)
        if request.user==post.user: '''I think this if is not true even when the post is created by the same user who is requesting to delete it.'''
            post.delete()
            print("ok")  
        return redirect("home")
```

Now when click on delete post it returns to home page but the post remains same.it doesn't delete the post.

Comment: Are you checking correctly ? Does ```Post``` model has a ```user``` ? Could you post Post model.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes

Comment: @jarmod, What's the relation between the question and the link you provided ?

Comment: @PrOgRaMmEr I'm assuming that both request.user and post.user are (likely) distinct objects representing the same user. They're not equal, unless the underlying User class correctly implements `__eq__` (for example to define equality based on user ID).

Comment: yes post model have user user = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in more cleaner way

```
@login_required
def delete_post(request , id):
    try:
        Post.objects.filter(pk=id, user=request.user).delete()
    except Exception:
        raise NotFoundError('The post you are trying to delte not found')
    return redirect("home")
```

No one can delete another user created post this way

Comment: @JyotiJha If it works, please accept the answer and make an upvote, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If `request.user` is not the `post.owner`, then it will not delete the post, but it will make a redirect to the `home` view.

Normally one should *not* create, update or remove items with a GET request, since GET requests are supposed to be *safe* and only *retrieve* data. You thus should limit this view to a POST request (or perhaps a POST or DELETE request).

You can work with the [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) to return a HTTP 404 response in case the object does not exist, or is not owned by the current user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@login_required
@require_POST
def delete_post(request , id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id, owner=request.user).delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to POST requests with the
> [**`@require_POST`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST).