# Python comparison between built-in and user-defined types

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, comparison, built-in

How does Python 3 compare a built-in object (on the lhs) to a user-defined object (on the rhs)?

Does the built-in `__eq__` method simply delegate the comparison to the rhs (`rhs.__eq__(self)`)?

I didn't find any statement about this in the docs. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) state:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal.

It's quite misleading because:

```
class X:
  def __eq__(self, rhs)
    return True

x = X()
'abc' == x # True
```

I think the doc statement should be rephrased as follows:

> Objects of different built-in types, except different numeric types, never compare equal.

and should furthermore clarify how the comparison to user-defined class instances is performed.

Comment: I take your point about the wording, but to be fair, the section is called "Built-in Types", and the first sentence is "The following sections describe the standard types that are built into the interpreter".  Other sentences, like "Any object can be tested for truth value", also assume that you haven't defined `def __bool__(self): raise Exception` or something.

Comment: @DSM Yeah, I realized the same on second reading. Thing is, many people read just short excerpts from the docs; the amount of context this passage requires for proper interpretation is quite beyond my normal attention range!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the questions:

> How does Python 3 compare a built-in object (on the lhs) to a user-defined object (on the rhs)?

The same way as with any other object comparisons (including `None`!).

> Does the built-in `__eq__` method simply delegate the comparison to the rhs (`rhs.__eq__(self)`)?

No. The built-in `__eq__` does *not* delegate like this. There is a higher-construct at work that covers the behavior of `==` in Python.

Given `a == b`, where `a.__eq__(b)` *returns* `NotImplemented` then `b.__eq__(a)` will be invoked and the result of the used as the result of the equality test. (`False` is returned if both `__eq__` implementations return `NotImplemented`.)

Thus, given `x` (of class `X`), and given that `"abc".__eq__(x)` *returns* `NotImplemented`, then `x.__eq__("abc")` is invoked (and evaluates to `True` per the question).

The same applies to the other standard comparison operators.

While I don't care to speculate too much on the documentation (or possible mis-wording), I believe it is entirely accurate *if* taken in context of `stdObj.__eq__(obj)` as opposed to `stdObj == obj`.

See also:

- The [documentation on the `__eq__` protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) which briefly mentions `NotImplemented`
- [Why return NotImplemented instead of raising NotImplementedError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplmented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror)

Comment: Thanks.. A minor point, but I think delegating (i.e., returning `rhs.__eq__(self)`) would have the same effect as returning NotImplemented, no?

Comment: @max I was just thinking about that on the way home. While perhaps being semantically equivalent in this particular case, it would not work where the lhs was a custom type that did not have such a delegating-`__eq__` implementation and it *could* lead to cases of infinite recursion if not written in a very precise manner -- both `(1).__eq__("x")` and `"x".__eq__(1)` evaluate to `NotImplemented`, for instance.

Comment: Yeah, I was only thinking about the specific case - in general, the NotImplemented-based mechanism is quite useful.