# Python comparison operator overloading

Tags: python, datetime, comparison, operator-overloading

For my Python 2.7.3 project I have a class called `custom_date`, which has a property called `fixed_date`:

```
from datetime import date
class custom_date():
    def __init__(self, fixed_date):
        self.fixed_date = fixed_date

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.fixed_date < other

    #__gt__, __ge__, __le__, __eq__, __ne__ all implemented the same way
```

My idea is to be able to directly compare `custom_date.fixed_date` with the builtin `date`.

**Problem**

If I compare a `custom_date` object to a `date` object, it's fine. However, if I compare a `date` object to a `custom_date`, it returns a `TypeError`

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> x = custom_date(date(2013,2,1))
>>> y = date(2013,2,2)
>>> x > y
False
>>> y > x
TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to instance
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subclass `date` to get this functionality. Since a datetime object is immutable, you need to use the `__new__` constructor vs `__init__`:

```
from datetime import date
class custom_date(date):
    def __new__(cls, year,month,day):
        return date.__new__(cls, year, month,day)

x = custom_date(2013,2,1)
y = date(2013,2,2)

print x<y
print y<x
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```

Since the determinative class for comparisons is the [LH class](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__lt__#object.__lt__), the class on the left needs to have the correct comparison operators to deal with the comparison with the class on the right. If there are no comparison operators for either class, instances are sorted by identity -- their memory address. Your error is essentially from trying to compare an apple to an orange: identity to a date class.

Note that there used to be a **rcmp** [that was removed](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rcmp__) in Python 2.1 to deal with such issues. Introduction of [the new style classes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) and [rich comparisons](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/) have also led to `__cmp__` being deprecated.

Comment: Good answer, but the OP's own answer is the 'correct' (and simpler) solution as it doesn't force you to unnecessarily subclass date.

Answer (score 4):

I think I know why you are running into problems. Check the [data model documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__lt__#object.__lt__) on docs.python.org.

```
>>> y > x
```

calls:

```
y.__gt__(x)
```

x is just an instance object, not the fixed_date attribute stored in it:

```
>>> x
<__main__.custom_date instance at 0x020D78C8>
>>> x.fixed_date
datetime.date(2012, 2, 1)
```

One way to make it work the way you have it set up is to do:

```
>>> y > x.fixed_date
```

I think to "fix" this, you would have make all your dates of type custom_date. Somebody else may have a better solution for you, and I'll be watching, because I'm curious as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was hoping there would be a way to do 'reflected' comparison, like `__radd__` vs `__add__`. Seems like it's not possible for comparison operators though.

Answer (score 2):

Found a potential solution, in case anyone else is facing the same problem.

From the [Python datetime docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects):

> > In other words, date1 < date2 if and only if date1.toordinal() < date2.toordinal(). In order to stop comparison from falling back to the default scheme of comparing object addresses, date comparison normally raises TypeError if the other comparand isn’t also a date object. **However, NotImplemented is returned instead if the other comparand has a timetuple() attribute. This hook gives other kinds of date objects a chance at implementing mixed-type comparison.** If not, when a date object is compared to an object of a different type, TypeError is raised unless the comparison is == or !=. The latter cases return False or True, respectively.

If `x.__op__(y)` returns `NotImplemented` instead of raising a `TypeError`, Python would automatically attempt the reverse comparison `y.__rop__(x)` (More info about comparisons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplmented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror)).

`date` however raises a `TypeError` if the other object isn't a `date` object, **unless the other object implements the timetuple() attribute**.

So the solution is to add a dummy `timetuple()` method to my class.

```
from datetime import date
class custom_date():
    def __init__(self, fixed_date):
        self.fixed_date = fixed_date

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.fixed_date < other

    #__gt__, __ge__, __le__, __eq__, __ne__ all implemented the same way

    def timetuple():
        pass
```

Comment: I think you should unaccept @dawg's answer and accept this!