# Why is NotImplemented evaluated multiple times with __eq__ operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

### Don’t mix up apples and oranges

#### The problem

I’m playing with the `__eq__` operator and the `NotImplemented` value.

I’m trying to understand what’s happen when `obj1.__eq__(obj2)` returns `NotImplemented` and `obj2.__eq__(obj1)` also returns `NotImplemented`.

According to the answer to **[Why return NotImplemented instead of raising NotImplementedError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/post/879005)**, and the detailed article **[How to override comparison operators in Python](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/32837.html)** in the "LiveJournal" blog, the runtime should fall back to the built-in behavior (which is based on identity for `==` and `!=`).

#### Code sample

But, trying the example bellow, it seems that I have multiple calls to `__eq__` for each pair of objects.

```
class Apple(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Apple color='{color}'>".format(color=self.color)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Apple):
            print("{self} == {other} -> OK".format(self=self, other=other))
            return self.color == other.color
        print("{self} == {other} -> NotImplemented".format(self=self, other=other))
        return NotImplemented


class Orange(object):
    def __init__(self, usage):
        self.usage = usage

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Orange usage='{usage}'>".format(usage=self.usage)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Orange):
            print("{self} == {other}".format(self=self, other=other))
            return self.usage == other.usage
        print("{self} == {other} -> NotImplemented".format(self=self, other=other))
        return NotImplemented

>>> apple = Apple("red")
>>> orange = Orange("juice")

>>> apple == orange
<Apple color='red'> == <Orange usage='juice'> -> NotImplemented
<Orange usage='juice'> == <Apple color='red'> -> NotImplemented
<Orange usage='juice'> == <Apple color='red'> -> NotImplemented
<Apple color='red'> == <Orange usage='juice'> -> NotImplemented
False
```

#### Expected behavior

I expected to have only:

```
<Apple color='red'> == <Orange usage='juice'> -> NotImplemented
<Orange usage='juice'> == <Apple color='red'> -> NotImplemented
```

Then falling back to identity comparison `id(apple) == id(orange)` -> `False`.

Comment: I'm on Python 2.7 OS X

Comment: Same behavior with Python 2.7 on Windows and CentOS7. Normal behavior on Python 3.5 on Windows and on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Dd0V/0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [issue #6970](http://bugs.python.org/issue6970) in the Python tracker; it remains unfixed in 2.7 and Python 3.0 and 3.1.

This is caused by **two places** trying both the straight and the swapped comparison when a comparison between two custom classes with `__eq__` methods is executed.

Rich comparisons go through the [`PyObject_RichCompare()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Objects/object.c#l938), which for objects with different types (indirectly) delegates to [`try_rich_compare()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Objects/object.c#l593). In this function `v` and `w` are the left and right operand objects, and since both have a `__eq__` method the function calls both `v->ob_type->tp_richcompare()` and `w->ob_type->tp_richcompare()`.

For custom classes, the [`tp_richcompare()` slot](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare) is defined as the [`slot_tp_richcompare()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Objects/typeobject.c#l5603), and this function *again* executes `__eq__` for both sides, first `self.__eq__(self, other)` then `other.__eq__(other, self)`.

In the end, that means `apple.__eq__(apple, orange)` and `orange.__eq__(orange, apple)` is called for the first attempt in `try_rich_compare()`, and then the reverse is called, resulting in the `orange.__eq__(orange, apple)` and `apple.__eq__(apple, orange)` calls as `self` and `other` are swapped in `slot_tp_richcompare()`.

Note that the issue is limited to instances of differing custom classes where *both classes* define an `__eq__` method. If either side doesn't have such a method `__eq__` is only executed once:

```
>>> class Pear(object):
...     def __init__(self, purpose):
...         self.purpose = purpose
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "<Pear purpose='{purpose}'>".format(purpose=self.purpose)
...    
>>> pear = Pear("cooking")
>>> apple == pear
<Apple color='red'> == <Pear purpose='cooking'> -> NotImplemented
False
>>> pear == apple
<Apple color='red'> == <Pear purpose='cooking'> -> NotImplemented
False
```

If you have two instances *of the same type* and `__eq__` returns `NotImplemented`, you get **six** comparisons even:

```
>>> class Kumquat(object):
...     def __init__(self, variety):
...         self.variety = variety
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "<Kumquat variety=='{variety}'>".format(variety=self.variety)
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         # Kumquats are a weird fruit, they don't want to be compared with anything
...         print("{self} == {other} -> NotImplemented".format(self=self, other=other))
...         return NotImplemented
...
>>> Kumquat('round') == Kumquat('oval')
<Kumquat variety=='round'> == <Kumquat variety=='oval'> -> NotImplemented
<Kumquat variety=='oval'> == <Kumquat variety=='round'> -> NotImplemented
<Kumquat variety=='round'> == <Kumquat variety=='oval'> -> NotImplemented
<Kumquat variety=='oval'> == <Kumquat variety=='round'> -> NotImplemented
<Kumquat variety=='oval'> == <Kumquat variety=='round'> -> NotImplemented
<Kumquat variety=='round'> == <Kumquat variety=='oval'> -> NotImplemented
False
```

The first set of two comparisons were called from an attempt at optimising; when two instances have the same type, you only need to call `v->tp_richcompare(v, w)` and coercions (for numbers) can be skipped, after all. However, when that comparison fails (`NotImplemented` is returned), then the standard path is *also* tried.

How comparisons are done in Python 2 got rather complicated as the older `__cmp__` 3-way comparison method still had to be supported; in Python 3, with support for `__cmp__` dropped, it was easier to fix the issue. As such, the fix was never backported to 2.7.

Comment: Man, I searched the bug tracker but could not find anything about this. And the source code for it was sufficiently spread out that I gave up on figuring out where it was doing the double fallback check (I found where defining a `__cmp__` as well as the `__eq__` would cause yet a third round of checking, but not this). Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I took a quick look at the sample with gdb (giving me a backtrace that fingered `slot_tp_richcompare` each time) and then searched for `slot_tp_richcompare` in the tracker, unearthing that report.