# Why does == not raise 'TypeError not supported' when all methods return NotImplemented?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the == operator return a value when all the comparison dunder methods are returning `NotImplemented`?  Other operators (<, <=,...) would raise a `TypeError` in the same situation.

To give an example, consider the following classes :

```
class Foo:
    pass
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('Foo __eq__', self, other)
        return NotImplemented
    
    def __ne__(self, other):
        print('Foo __ne__', self, other)
        return NotImplemented
    
class Bar:
    pass
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('Bar __eq__', self, other)
        return NotImplemented
        
    def __ne__(self, other):
        print('Bar __ne__', self, other)
        return NotImplemented
```

We have the following behavior:

```
# Foo __eq__ and Bar __eq__ called
assert not Foo() == Bar()

# Foo __eq__ called twice
f=Foo()
assert f==f
```

No exception raised. == seems to use the default implementation based on object identity if nothing else is available.

If I try the same experiment with < instead of == I'll end up with a TypeError exception :

```
# assuming __lt__ and __gt__ implemented in Foo and Bar to return NotImplemented
Foo() < Bar()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Foo' and 'Bar'
```

What do I have to do if I want prevent == comparison between objects of a certain class?

Comment: Returning `NotImplemented` basically means "dunno, ask someone else." That someone else is eventually `object.__eq__`.

Comment: You can raise a `TypeError` explicitly in `__eq__` if that is the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the options would be (a) return `False`, like `float('NaN')` does, or (b) raise an exception in `__eq__` for an inappropriate comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588737/4779042) equality doesn't raise an exception but uses a different fallback. So first it tries to compare the classes as you give, then because it is not implemented it tries the swapped version for equality (the reason for calling it twice). Then it falls back to identity comparison

```
eq -> same objects? -> True, else False

ne -> different objects? True, else False
```