# How does == behave when __eq__ is not defined in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was not able to find anything useful in [the documentation for Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__). However, [the docs for 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) state:

> By default, `object` implements `__eq__()` by using `is`, returning
> `NotImplemented` in the case of a false comparison: `True if x is y else NotImplemented`.

This seems to be right for Python 3.6 as well.

```
class Foo():
    pass

print(Foo().__eq__(Foo())) # prints NotImplemented
```

However, I don't understand why

```
print(Foo() == Foo()) # prints False
```

prints not `NotImplemented`, but `False`. What is `==` doing here?

Comment: If equality is not implemented, Python says they must not be equal.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is not true. `f = Foo(); f == f` evaluates to `True` even if `__eq__` is not implemented in `Foo`

Comment: Because then they're _identical_.

Answer (score 2):

When `__eq__` is not defined Python computes `object.__eq__(a, b)` which returns True if and only if they are the same object.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63310298/3275464 for more details.

Comment: `object.__eq__(Foo(), Foo())` is _also_ `NotImplemented`, not `False`.

Comment: The key thing to understand is that `a == b` is not equal to `__eq__(a, b)`, but that it is equal to a function that calls `__eq__` and - given `__eq__(a, b)` returns `NotImplemented` - returns `a is b`. This is explained in the answer linked above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592404/10680954

Comment: @zwithouta Indeed you are correct, I glossed over this important detail, the link I shared does contain this info still ;)