# If 2 nodes have same value and their child nodes have same value, upon comparing using "==" operator in python, I was expecting the output to be True

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,left=None,right=None,val=0):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
        self.val=val

#creating a tree      
abc=Node(val=1)
abc.left=Node(val=2)
abc.right=Node(val=2)
abc.left.left=Node(val=3)
abc.left.right=Node(val=3)
abc.right.left=Node(val=3)
abc.right.right=Node(val=3)

print(abc.left == abc.right)  

Output: False
```

I Understand they can be stored in different memory locations but "==" operator compares the equality or value of 2 objects. So how are the 2 nodes different?.

This is what ChatGPT told me, is it correct?

> the == operator compares the values in the case of lists, but compares the objects themselves in the case of instances of a class like Node.

Comment: They both are distinct objects. `abc.left,abc.right` and `==` operator check both `values` as well as `object`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it output `False` you are creating both objects as ***distinct***. `==` operator checks the *value* as well as the *object* **hence as they are distinct it will return False**

To make the `abc.left==abc.right -> True` you need to assign both as a same `object`.

**Code:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,left=None,right=None,val=0):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
        self.val=val
    
abc=Node(val=1)
abc.left=Node(val=2)
abc.right=abc.left  # Assigning abc.right as the same object as abc.left
abc.left.left=Node(val=3)
abc.left.right=Node(val=3)
abc.right.left=Node(val=3)
abc.right.right=Node(val=3)

print(abc.left == abc.right) #True
```

Comment: as per my understanding "==" focuses only on equality, "is" operator focuses on identity,
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
print(hex(id(a)),hex(id(b)))
print(a==b) --> true
print(a is b) --> false
"a" and "b" are different objects but on comparision using "==" give True as output

Comment: But `==` defaults to `is` for objects, unless you define your own `__eq__` function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685342/20172954 see the answer and the link provided by this answer.. This will clear your doubt. @User_04_04_2023