# Force child class to override parent's methods

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Suppose I have a base class with unimplemented methods as follows:

```
class Polygon():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def perimeter(self):
        pass

    def area(self):
        pass
```

Now, let's say one of my colleagues uses the Polygon class to create a subclass as follows:

```
import math

class Circle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius
```

(H/Sh)e has forgotten to implement the area() method.

How can I force the subclass to implement the parent's area() method?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

this could be your parent class:

```
class Polygon():

    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def perimeter(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def area(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

although the problem will be spotted at runtime only, when one of the instances of the child classes tries to call one of these methods.

---

a different version is to use [`abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod).

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import math


class Polygon(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def perimeter(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def area(self):
        pass

class Circle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius

#    def area(self):
#        return math.pi * self.radius**2


c = Circle(9.0)
# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Circle
#            with abstract methods area
```

you will not be able to instantiate a `Circle` without it having all the methods implemented.

this is the `python 3` syntax; in `python 2` you'd need to

```
class Polygon(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
```

---

also note that for the binary special functions  `__eq__(), __lt__(), __add__(), ...` it is better to [`return NotImplemented`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575926/4954037) instead of raising `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: I would put your 2nd option as the primary, letting the 1st an alternative option with drawbacks. Following the Zen of python I would only keep the simple version of your 2nd option since it is simpler and works just fine.

Comment: Is there anyway to enforce return type / type hint on overridden method?

Comment: no. python itself does not enforce any type hints. you need a static type checker for that.

Answer (score 7):

You can raise [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError) exception in base class method.

```
class Polygon:
    def area(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Also you can use [`@abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod), but then you need to declare metaclass to be [`abc.ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta), which would make your class abstract. More about [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#module-abc)

Answer (score 7):

That's exactly what `NotImplementedError` are used for :)

In your base class

```
def area(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("Hey, Don't forget to implement the area!")
```

Comment: This only works when you are trying to call the `area()` method. If you want to really force a user to implement all the methods, ABC module is needed.