# Python Check if Methods or interface is implemented before runtime

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating an interface Mixins that contains methods that will throw error if it is not implemented, however it only happens during run time when the method is called, i would like to have python check if method is implemented before run time.

```
class TestInterface():
    def get_testing_name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def do_something(self):
        return self.get_testing_name()


class Testing(TestInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        super().do_something()
```

In my Testing class, i didn't defined **get_testing_name** method, hence it will **raise NotImplementedError**. However this will **only** happen **on run time**

**How** do i make sure python **check** if method is not implemented **before run time**?

Comment: this may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576167/force-child-class-to-override-parents-methods/44576235#44576235

Comment: If it is before runtime, then probably it should be done by the IDE? In such a case, most of the IDE could inspect whether an abstract method is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you.
Maybe that was what you wanted ?:

```
try:
    t = Testing()
except NotImplementedError:
    print("Fail")
```