# Force child class to override parent's class attribute

Tags: python, oop

Based on this question: [Force child class to override parent's methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576167/force-child-class-to-override-parents-methods/44576235), my need is to set an attribute in the class that must be overridden by the child:

```
class Parent(ABC):
    property = None # this one must be defined

# this should fail
class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's an attribute equivalent to abstract methods.

Comment: `Parent.__init__()` could check `self.property`, and throw an exception if it still has the default value.

Comment: @jasonharper That won't raise an error until you actually try to instantiate `Child`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) (which was intended to provide metaclass-like functionality via simple inheritance).

```
class Parent:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if not hasattr(cls, 'property'):
            raise TypeError("Subclass must define class attribute 'property'")

class ChildThatWorks(Parent):
    property = 3

class ChildThatFails(Parent):
    pass
```

An interesting option is to pass `property` as an keyword argument, rather than an assignment in the body of the class statement.

```
class Parent:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, property, **kwargs):
        setattr(cls, 'property', property)

class ChildThatWorks(Parent, property=3):
    pass

class ChildThatFails(Parent):
    pass
```

`ChildThatFails` will produce the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chepner/tmp.py", line 8, in <module>
    class ChildThatFails(Parent):
TypeError: __init_subclass__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'property'
```

The code is simpler, but you have less flexibility in how you handle the failure to provide the `property` value.

Comment: I think there is also should be checking wether `property` is not equal to `None` (keeping in mind the code from the question).

Comment: In this answer, `Parent` simply doesn't define `property` at all, rather than assigning it some sentinel value.