# How to annotate `__eq__` when it uses an attribute?

Tags: python, python-typing

Given the following class, how should I annotate `__eq__`?

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return Foo.bar == other.bar
```

Using `__eq__(self, other: Foo) -> bool` makes `mypy` error with:

> `Argument 1 of "__eq__" is incompatible with supertype "object"; supertype defines the argument type as "object"`

and using `__eq__(self, other: object) -> bool` makes `mypy` error with:

> `"object" has no attribute "bar"`

What should I do?

Comment: nit: did you mean `self.bar` instead of `Foo.bar` in return value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended that `__eq__` works with arbitrary objects. In this example, you would need to guard that `other` is a member of the `Foo` class first:

```py
def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(other, Foo):
        return NotImplemented
    return Foo.bar == other.bar
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl It's preferable to `return NotImplemented` rather than `raise NotImplementedError`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplemented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror

Answer (score 1):

`object.__eq__()` must handle any type of object, not just your own class. Return `NotImplemented` for types you don't want to handle, so Python can ask the right-hand-side operand if it wants to handle equality testing.

Annotate the `other` argument as `object` as per the [Python typeshed guidelines](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#conventions):

```
def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(other, Foo):
        return NotImplemented
    return Foo.bar == other.bar
```

Setting `other` to `object` essentially tells typecheckers that anything that inherits from `object` (which in Python is *everything*) is acceptable. The `isinstance(other, Foo)` test tells a type checker that any object that makes it to the last line of the function is not only an instance of `object`, but specifically an instance of `Foo` or a further subclass.

Comment: I disagree with using Any here. While both Any and object mean "anything can be passed in here", Any has the additional downside of meaning "also, please subvert the type system". So, using it is counter-productive if your goal is to ensure your code is statically typed -- it's really only meant to be an escape hatch when you're unable to adequately express something using types. The [Typeshed contribution guidelines](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#conventions) goes into a little more detail about this.

Comment: `object.__eq__` is canonically defined to [accept object](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L47) in typeshed for this very reason. (So to be consistent/as per Liskov, it's probably best if all subclasses do the same.) It is however definitely true that type checkers are not obligated to understand isinstance checks. But all of them seem to, so I'm not sure if that's really an issue in practice.

Comment: @Michael0x2a: ick, indeed, that typeshed reference is pretty definitive. I'll have to hunt out the [incorrect type annotations in typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/efb67946f88494e5e9a273d59a3100a56514b15f/stdlib/3/email/charset.pyi#L24) to avoid making the same mistake again.