# Make sum of object using __magic_methods__

Tags: python, sum

can I do in python magic like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a_list = [A(1), A(3)]

sum_x = sum(a_list)
```

I know about this solution:

```
sum_x = sum([elem.x for elem in a_list])
```

But I want to do it using magic methods

Comment: You're looking for the add dunder method.

Answer (score 2):

To make this example work, you can implement [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#emulating-numeric-types) magic method (but I recommend to implement `__add__`/`__iadd__` as well + comparison operators):

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __radd__(self, other):
        match other:
            case int(x):
                return self.x + x
            case A():
                return self.x + other.x
            case _:
                return NotImplemented


a_list = [A(1), A(3)]

sum_x = sum(a_list)
print(sum_x)
```

Prints:

```
4
```

---

<sup>EDIT: Raise `NotImplementedError` if arguments don't match. Thanks @Anentropic</sup>

Comment: Great. __radd__ in what I need! Thanks

Comment: it should check `isinstance(other, A)` before `return self.x + other.x` else return `NotImplemented` (according to the docs linked)

Comment: the docs say to return `NotImplemented` rather than raise `NotImplementedError`, perhaps it should be that e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575926/202168